# Strings for my guitar - I'm supposed to tie a knot, but they have a loop

Tags: acoustic-guitar, strings

I'm a new guitar player and found an old acoustic guitar in the attic which had rusty strings.
I bought some Elixir Phosphor bronze acoustic strings, but now that I have received them I'm kinda confused.

[Pictures for visual aid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KrOgM.jpg)

Above you will find some pictures.
I let one string stay for ease of clarification.
My understanding of my guitar is that I have to tie it with a knot just like the last string is right now as there are no pins, but the Elixir strings has this loop.
Can I use them anyway and how would I tie them with the loop? :)
To be honest I am also confused that it says 3/4 acoustic, concert and classical guitar on the label inside the guitar, I understand that 3/4 means size but can it be all three at the same time?

Comment: Just to avoid any further confusion, if you have any luthier or music store in your area, I recommend getting their help with picking out strings; they ought to be able to show you how to put them on, too.

Comment: As John says, if you have put the strings on, take them off immediately! They're not the correct ones for that guitar! They will single-handedly wreck it in one go!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The instrument in the photo is a *classical* guitar, not *acoustic*. It uses nylon strings: the three treble strings are from plain nylon (like the one remaining on the photo), and the three bass strings are nylon fibers with metal wound, unlike acoustic/electric guitar strings which have steel core.

Don't put metal (acoustic or electric) strings on a classical guitar. See e.g. [Putting a steel string on a classical guitar? (classical guitar with truss rods)](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/25682/putting-a-steel-string-on-a-classical-guitar-classical-guitar-with-truss-rods)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139996/discussion-on-answer-by-user1079505-strings-for-my-guitar-im-supposed-to-tie).

Answer (score 14):

…and just to reinforce user1079505’s answer, if you did manage to put them on remove them immediately. A classical guitar is designed for about 1/2 to 1/3 the string tension of a steel string acoustic so you can easily damage the neck or bridge or both with steel strings.